# HTML - How to <div> directly next to <td> but not moving table columns

Tags: css, html

I have a basic 2 column table for a form. In the left column are the labels, and in the right column are the inputs. When the user submits the form, if there are errors I want to display them directly to the right of the input in which the error was relating to. Could anyone provide an example of how to position a div next to the table row without shifting the columns across?

Comment: You need to provide a minimal example of your code and what you have tried so far. This way you can get specific solutions without playing 20 questions to get to the answer you need. For example, have you tried adding the div to the page and using floats?

Answer (score 1):

You could have the `<div>` representing the error inside of the `<tr>`. If there is no error it could just be empty. You can use a js templating framework like [Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) to pass arguments into your `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage the use of Flex Grid.  This is a CSS ruleset that will help you layout your form.  You can still use two column format, with the only change being the you will probably want to reduce the size of the first column relative to the second column, to leave room for an error message.

Another option would be to use abandon tables and use CSS Grids instead.

Take a look at these links for more information:

- http://flexboxgrid.com/
- https://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-flexbox-grids/
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/